# Writing a 2D Array to a string, then to a .txt file - Java

Tags: java, string, file, multidimensional-array

I have a Method that calls a second method, the second method will:

- Create any missing directories
- Create a file
- Decode a 2D String[] to a String (Not working)
- Write content
- Write the decoded String to the file with a header (Not working)

First method

```
public static boolean store(Exception exception, String[][] flags){
    return storePrivate(exception, location, flags);
}
```

Second Method (Not all code just relevant code)

```
private static boolean storePrivate(Exception exception, String dir, String[][] flags){
    String flag = "";

    for(int i = 0; i >= flags.length; i++){
        flag = flag + "" +  flags[i][0] + ": " + flags[i][1] + "\n";
    }
    try {
        File directory = new File(dir);
        File file = new File(dir + id + ".txt");
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs(); 
        }
        file.createNewFile();
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);


        if(flag != ""){
            writer.write("Flags by Developer: ");
            writer.write(flag);
        }   
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call to the first method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        test();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ExceptionAPI.store(e, new String[][]{{"flag1", "Should be part of flag1"}, {"flag2", "this should be flag 2 contence"}});
    }
}

public static void test() throws IOException{
    throw new IOException();
}
```

I cant find why this won't work. I think it has to do with the second method, particularly

```
if(flag != ""){
    writer.write("Flags by Developer: ");
    writer.write(flag);
}
```

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Curlip

Comment: What is the use of the `Exception` in the method?

Comment: As @ambigram_maker pointed out in a comment to the first answer, your loop condition `i >= flags.length` is wrong and should instead be `i < flags.length`. You initialize `i` to `0`, which is not greater than or equal to `flags.length` when it contains any elements (`length` will be `1`).

Comment: @ambigram_maker part of the code I left out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you want to just convert an array of strings into a single string:

```
    String[] stringTwoD = //... I think this is a 1D array, and Sting[][] is a 2D, anyway
    String stringOneD = "";
    for (String s : stringTwoD) 
        stringOneD += s;//add the string with the format you want
```

BTW, your loop condition seems wrong and ,so you may change it to  :

```
for(int i = 0; i < flags.length; i++){
    flag += flags[i][0] + ": " + flags[i][1] + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Exactly... OP writes `... i >= flags.length; i++)... `

Comment: You'd better use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @ambigram_maker> I just wanted to notify him/her about the change he should make. I'll add that approach too.

Comment: `OP` is generally accepted instead of `him/her`. (Just sayin')

Comment: OP's Array is 2-dimensional though (`String[][]`). His approach is basically fine except the `i >= flags.length` as @ambigram_maker pointed out.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers> Exactly, I just updated my answer. I was mislead by "Decode a 2D String[] to a String (Not working)"

Comment: Update your _previous_ snippet as well, changing it to 2D array.

Comment: I'm not the best at Java but It's my preferred language

Comment: @user3547934> Well, why do you say that?

Comment: Just in case my code is more complected than it needs to be

Comment: Stupit Mistake on my part

Comment: @user3547934> No problem, we all make such mistakes and it will decrease with passing time.